# MongoDB doesn't work on Karaf 4.0.8 with Camel 2.18.1

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel, karaf, blueprint-osgi

We created a simple test bundle, but as soon as we try to use MongoDB in one of our Camel routes, the route does not start anymore.

The blueprint is quite simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
         http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.1.0.xsd">

    <bean id="mongo" class="com.mongodb.Mongo">
        <argument value="localhost"/>
    </bean>

    <camelContext id="blueprint-bean-context"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

        <route id="testTimer">
            <from uri="timer:testTimer?period=5000" />

            <setBody>
                <spel>{"type": "product"}</spel>
            </setBody>
            <to uri="mongodb:mongo?database=testdb&amp;collection=mycollection&amp;operation=findAll" />
            <log message="Result was queried" />

        </route>
    </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

MongoDB is added as a dependency in the POM. The excerpt of the log in DEBUG mode gives these lines:

```
2017-01-24 13:41:27,672 | DEBUG | raf-4.0.8/deploy | ReferenceRecipe                  | 12 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.7.1 | Binding reference .camelBlueprint.languageResolver.spel to [org.apache.camel.spi.LanguageResolver]
2017-01-24 13:41:27,672 | DEBUG | raf-4.0.8/deploy | BlueprintLanguageResolver        | 55 - org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint - 2.18.1 | Found language resolver: spel in registry: org.apache.camel.impl.osgi.Activator$BundleLanguageResolver@6841375f
2017-01-24 13:41:27,673 | DEBUG | raf-4.0.8/deploy | DefaultChannel                   | 58 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.18.1 | Initialize channel for target: 'SetBody[spel{SpelExpression[{"type": "product"}]}]'
2017-01-24 13:41:27,673 | DEBUG | raf-4.0.8/deploy | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 12 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.7.1 | Instantiating component blueprintBundle
2017-01-24 13:41:27,676 | DEBUG | raf-4.0.8/deploy | DefaultManagementAgent           | 58 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.18.1 | Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=de.test.bundle-x1-blueprint-bean-context,type=tracer,name=BacklogTracer
2017-01-24 13:41:27,676 | DEBUG | raf-4.0.8/deploy | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 12 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.7.1 | Instantiating component blueprintBundle
2017-01-24 13:41:27,680 | DEBUG | raf-4.0.8/deploy | DefaultManagementAgent           | 58 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.18.1 | Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=de.test.bundle-x1-blueprint-bean-context,type=tracer,name=BacklogDebugger
2017-01-24 13:41:27,683 | DEBUG | raf-4.0.8/deploy | DefaultManagementAgent           | 58 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.18.1 | Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=de.test.bundle-x1-blueprint-bean-context,type=errorhandlers,name="DefaultErrorHandlerBuilder(ref:CamelDefaultErrorHandlerBuilder)"
2017-01-24 13:41:27,686 | DEBUG | raf-4.0.8/deploy | DefaultComponent                 | 58 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.18.1 | Creating endpoint uri=[mongodb://mongo?collection=processing_requests&database=genex&operation=findAll], path=[mongo]
2017-01-24 13:41:27,686 | DEBUG | raf-4.0.8/deploy | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 12 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.7.1 | Instantiating component mongo
2017-01-24 13:41:27,687 | INFO  | raf-4.0.8/deploy | BlueprintCamelContext            | 58 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.18.1 | Apache Camel 2.18.1 (CamelContext: blueprint-bean-context) is shutting down
2017-01-24 13:41:27,687 | DEBUG | raf-4.0.8/deploy | efaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager | 58 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.18.1 | Shutting down with no inflight threads.
2017-01-24 13:41:27,688 | DEBUG | raf-4.0.8/deploy | TimerListenerManager             | 58 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.18.1 | Removed TimerListener: org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedCamelContext@1350b665
2017-01-24 13:41:27,688 | DEBUG | raf-4.0.8/deploy | DefaultManagementAgent           | 58 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.18.1 | Unregistered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=de.test.bundle-x1-blueprint-bean-context,type=context,name="blueprint-bean-context"
2017-01-24 13:41:27,688 | DEBUG | raf-4.0.8/deploy | DefaultInflightRepository        | 58 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.18.1 | Shutting down with no inflight exchanges.
```

Why does the Camel context start up and shutdown immediately? The timer is not executed and the log message never printed. As soon as we remove the `to` for calling MongoDB, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the bean declaration

```
<bean id="mongo" class="com.mongodb.Mongo">
```

to

```
<bean id="mongo" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
```

you can read more about it in the [official documentation](http://camel.apache.org/mongodb.html#MongoDB-ConfigurationofdatabaseinSpringXML) of the Mongo component for Camel.